# Remove punctuation in R but leave punctuation/"sentence markers" "!", ".", "?" at the end of a sentence

Tags: r, gsub, data-cleaning, lda, topic-modeling

I am currently trying to create a sentence-based LDA on a text corpus that I am working with. 
To detect sentences and split them I am using the `sent_detect()` function from the `openNLP` package.

However, the dataset I am working with is very unclean and contains a lot of other "punctuation" that I would like to get rid off before I use the `sent_detect()` function.

Usually, I would use the following code (from the `tm` package) on a text corpus to remove punctuation:
`text.corpus <- tm_map(text.corpus, removePunctuation)`

However, this function would remove all kind of punctuation, **including** **".", "?", "!", "|"** that are used by the `sent_detect()` function to detect sentences. Thus, it would ruin my aim to split the text into separate sentences.

Is there a way to remove punctuation but exclude specific "sentence-indicators" (*".", "?", "!", "|"** ) with the above `tm_map()` function?

**Here's a text example:**

> *not funny; - i did not like the movie / film at all (since the actors were terrible). however, i really enjoyed the scenery!*

Usually, the above `removePunctuation` would remove all punctuation symbols and leave the following sentence:

> *not funny i did not like the movie film at all since the actors were terrible however i really enjoyed the scenery*

However, what I want to end up with would be:

> *not funny i did not like the movie  film at all since the actors were terrible. however i really enjoyed the scenery!*

Thank you!

Ps: Using the openNLP package is not a must and I am also open to any other solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `stringr` and a not-not-statement (thanks to Chris Ruehlemann's comment):

```r
s <- "not funny; - i did not like the movie / film at all (since the actors were terrible). however, i really enjoyed the scenery!"

str_remove_all(s, "[^[^[[:punct:]]]!|.|?]")
[1] "not funny  i did not like the movie  film at all since the actors were terrible. however i really enjoyed the scenery!"
```

Comment: I actually don't know why this is working with `str_remove_all` and fails with `gsub`.

Comment: This solution leaves double whitespace characters at points where chars have been removed and escaping in character classes is not needed: `str_remove_all(s, "[^[^[[:punct:]]]!|.|?]")` prompts the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gsub` to define all the characters you want to remove as patterns, connecting them with the alternation marker `|` and making sure that metacharacters such as `(` and `)` are properly escaped with `\\`, and replace the patterns with `""`--that is, nothing--in the replacement argument:

```
gsub(";|- |/ |,|\\(|\\)", "", s)
[1] "not funny i did not like the movie film at all since the actors were terrible. however i really enjoyed the scenery!"
```

Data:

```
s <- "not funny; - i did not like the movie / film at all (since the actors were terrible). however, i really enjoyed the scenery!"
```